Deje dup and duplicity - restore fail
New and ignorant Ubuntu user. Hardly able to use a command line.
I had an old PC that I installed with Ubuntu version 22.04 LTS. I used the Ubuntu proposed backup tool DEJA DUP to start backing up a few selected files. A few weeks later, the old PC crashed. Bye bye.
I am now using a PC that I boot Windows on its local hard drive, and sometime I boot Ubuntu on an external Drive for Ubuntu (which Ubuntu is of a same version as lost PC one year ago).
I want to restore my archives that are in a home folder on this same external Drive.
As a complementary piece of information:
benoit@Surface-Pro-3:~$ ls -l
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root   4096 juil. 20 12:46 bureau
drwxrwxrwx 2 benoit benoit 4096 juil. 27 15:49 Bureau
drwxrwxrwx 4 benoit benoit 4096 juil. 27 15:45 Documents
drwxrwxrwx 2 benoit benoit 4096 févr. 11 14:59 Images
drwxrwxrwx 2 benoit benoit 4096 juil. 27 15:25 maison
drwxrwxrwx 2 benoit benoit 4096 févr. 11 14:59 Modèles
drwxrwxrwx 2 benoit benoit 4096 févr. 11 14:59 Musique
drwxrwxr-x 3 benoit benoit 4096 juil. 27 15:42 OneDrive_bejibe
drwxrwxrwx 2 benoit benoit 4096 févr. 11 14:59 Public
drwx------ 7 benoit benoit 4096 juil. 14 18:45 snap
drwxrwxrwx 2 benoit benoit 4096 juil. 27 15:18 Téléchargements
drwxrwxrwx 2 benoit benoit 4096 juil. 27 15:49 Vidéos

The archive files are in same drive, folder "maison":
benoit@Surface-Pro-3:~/maison$ ls -l
total 260612
-rw-rw-rw- 1 benoit benoit      2598 juil.  6  2023 duplicity-full.20230706T092526Z.manifest.gpg
-rw-rw-rw- 1 benoit benoit 209720636 juil.  6  2023 duplicity-full.20230706T092526Z.vol3.difftar.gpg
-rw-rw-rw- 1 benoit benoit  15396575 juil.  6  2023 duplicity-full.20230706T092526Z.vol4.difftar.gpg
-rw-rw-rw- 1 benoit benoit   4383858 juil.  6  2023 duplicity-full-signatures.20230706T092526Z.sigtar.gpg
-rw-rw-rw- 1 benoit benoit       693 juil. 15  2023 duplicity-inc.20230706T092526Z.to.20230715T095804Z.manifest.gpg
-rw-rw-rw- 1 benoit benoit     18507 juil. 15  2023 duplicity-inc.20230706T092526Z.to.20230715T095804Z.vol1.difftar.gpg
-rw-rw-rw- 1 benoit benoit      3606 juil. 23  2023 duplicity-inc.20230715T095804Z.to.20230723T112803Z.manifest.gpg
-rw-rw-rw- 1 benoit benoit  36755510 juil. 23  2023 duplicity-inc.20230715T095804Z.to.20230723T112803Z.vol1.difftar.gpg
-rw-rw-rw- 1 benoit benoit     11500 juil. 15  2023 duplicity-new-signatures.20230706T092526Z.to.20230715T095804Z.sigtar.gpg
-rw-rw-rw- 1 benoit benoit    546840 juil. 23  2023 duplicity-new-signatures.20230715T095804Z.to.20230723T112803Z.sigtar.gpg

I have tried a restore of the full date back-up archive with DEJA-DUP tool and it crashes.
I also have tried a restore of archive with a SU command line (I don't know how to specify the date, so I presume it tries the full date restore)
sudo duplicity restore file:///PathToBackupDIR PathToDestinationDir

and it crashes with exactly the same error message. Here it is:
Traceback (innermost last):
File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 92, in <module>
with_tempdir(main)
File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 75, in with_tempdir
fn()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1568, in main
do_backup(action)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1651, in do_backup
restore(col_stats)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 736, in restore
restore_get_patched_rop_iter(col_stats)):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 788, in restore_get_patched_rop_iter
file_names.append(backup_set.volume_name_dict[vol_num])
KeyError: 1

I only have one full archive, it was my first one ever done. And 2 incremential dates. All in july 2023, one year ago.
with DEJA-DUP, If I want to restore selected files of a sub-folder from a back-up,sometime it works for SOME files and NOT OTHER files, sometime with the full back-up date, sometime the incremential back-up date.
it's crasy! in one same sub-folder and one back-up date, some files can be restored, other files give error message.
For example, with DEJA-DUP, I managed to restore those files in their original folder (see list bellow of restored files) BUT the archive shown by DEJA-DUP in the same folder have more files that all give the error bellow.
benoit@Surface-Pro-3:~/OneDrive_bejibe/Images OneDrive/Camera Roll$ ls -l
total 156748
-rw-rw-r-- 1 benoit benoit  4068880 juin  18  2023 PXL_20230609_192446719.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 benoit benoit  2712051 juin  18  2023 PXL_20230611_175128889.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 benoit benoit  2970920 juin  18  2023 PXL_20230611_175304808.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 benoit benoit  3051820 juin  18  2023 PXL_20230611_175416024~2.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 benoit benoit  3308617 juin  18  2023 PXL_20230611_175416024.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 benoit benoit  4257834 juin  18  2023 PXL_20230613_113626825.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 benoit benoit  4853569 juin  18  2023 PXL_20230613_113634348.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 benoit benoit  4899359 juin  18  2023 PXL_20230613_113649255.MP.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 benoit benoit  4261302 juin  18  2023 PXL_20230613_113712546.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 benoit benoit  3954441 juin  18  2023 PXL_20230613_113728579.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 benoit benoit 99586113 juin  18  2023 PXL_20230613_123038623.mp4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 benoit benoit  5417782 juin  18  2023 PXL_20230613_123247011.MP.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 benoit benoit  5807504 juin  18  2023 PXL_20230613_123304330.MP.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 benoit benoit  5745175 juin  18  2023 PXL_20230613_123309285.MP.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 benoit benoit  5575688 juin  18  2023 PXL_20230613_123340419.MP.jpg

The content of the archive for the last incremental date (I don't know how to show for all the 3 dates), using command:
duplicity list-current-files file:///home/benoit/maison/

Returns a long list of files. I list bellow only the ones in the folder I want to restore, it is:
Sun Jul 23 12:24:34 2023 home/benoit/OneDrive_bejibe/Images OneDrive/Camera Roll
Sat Jan 16 14:25:40 2021 home/benoit/OneDrive_bejibe/Images OneDrive/Camera Roll/20201228_174833.jpg
Mon Aug 17 10:34:14 2020 home/benoit/OneDrive_bejibe/Images OneDrive/Camera Roll/P1050043.JPG
Mon Aug 17 10:32:25 2020 home/benoit/OneDrive_bejibe/Images OneDrive/Camera Roll/P1050044.JPG
Fri Aug 21 15:07:49 2020 home/benoit/OneDrive_bejibe/Images OneDrive/Camera Roll/P10500621.jpg
Fri Aug 21 15:11:21 2020 home/benoit/OneDrive_bejibe/Images OneDrive/Camera Roll/P10500631.jpg

For thos files above, I got the message:
Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.
    Last full backup date: none
    GnuPG passphrase for decryption: 
    Traceback (innermost last):
      File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 92, in <module>
        with_tempdir(main)
      File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 75, in with_tempdir
        fn()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1568, in main
        do_backup(action)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1651, in do_backup
        restore(col_stats)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 736, in restore
        restore_get_patched_rop_iter(col_stats)):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 758, in restore_get_patched_rop_iter
        backup_chain = col_stats.get_backup_chain_at_time(time)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_collections.py", line 1011, in get_backup_chain_at_time
        raise CollectionsError(u"No backup chains found")
     duplicity.dup_collections.CollectionsError: No backup chains found

When I run DEJA_DUP in debug mode, and try to restore a file I know is not restoring well, I get the message:
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 92, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 75, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1568, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1651, in do_backup
    restore(col_stats)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 736, in restore
    restore_get_patched_rop_iter(col_stats)):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 788, in restore_get_patched_rop_iter
    file_names.append(backup_set.volume_name_dict[vol_num])
 KeyError: 2

I have read the page "How to restore a broken deja dup backup manually", I do not understand anything. I am not at level.
ANY HELP?

Added Extra1 to answer

You should not use sudo for backups. The permissions / owners of the backups are probably all messed up now. I suggest checking that.

I have never used sudo for backups. Those arquives I tried to restore are one year old and had been generated with DEJA DUP software. What I try now is restoring. I have used sudo for restore comands only. I presume restore comand does not affect permission/owners of the arquives?

Please read again my question, since I have changed a lot because I was advised not to add new answers but rather edit the original question. Sorry about this, not very informed to the forum good practice rules.

Details are needed about exactly where the backups are stored. If on an external drive, please edit your question to show details of the mountpoint: owner, permissions, etc. You can get this by doing ls -l in a terminal. That same information is needed for the directories and the individual backup files where the backup is stored on the external drive: owner, permissions, etc. When I had these kind of problems years ago, it was caused by owner/permission settings, but it's been so long, I do not remember the details. It's easy to fix once the problem is found though.

I have added those information in the question.

Added Extra2 to answer

I have read somewhere that this sort of error is caused by identical target file names but with different extensions. You could try isolating the target files and repeat.
I think (you haven't posted your command lines) you have attempted to use duplicity directly. Something like: -
duplicity restore file:///PathToBackupDIR /PathToDestinationDir

That would restore the latest. See the man page for further options.
You might like to try different combinations such as extracting a specific directory or an older archive.
Hope this is or some help.
Extra1
If this has not been successful then, perhaps, you could list the duplicity files and post as part of your question. If all else fails you can have a go at restoring the files by hand (not for the novice) -see link below (note: its a bit old).
How to restore a broken Deja Dup backup manually
Hope this is of some help.

Added Extra2
Add a list of the files in the target archive.
Then try running deja-dup from a command line in debug mode as follow:
DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1 deja-dup | tail -n 200 | tee /tmp/deja-dup.log

(This is modified to also put debug data into terminal to make it easier to past to original question.)
repeating your original restore and then appending the result (the file at the end of the command) to the end of your original question.

Looking at the list of the backend (archive) you have posted it suggests that volume 1 & 2 are missing as they are normally generated in order. To confirm this I would need to see the log which I requested in my last posting. If you would like to see a similar log to see what I mean posted on another answer see: -
Deja Dup Backup Failed

Have added the list of the files I managed to restore in a folder.
I also have try in debug mode on a file I don't manage to restore, and pasted the result in the question.

I have tried to follow your Extra 1.
The command specifies all files ending with gz. I dont have any file ending gz, some ends gpg. I so run the same command with gpg. Some messages appear telling that they are not tar files

I did warn that the 'restore broken Deja-dup' link is not for the novice. It is an old link and made before the compression algorithm was changed so changing gz to gpg as you did sounds a reasonable modification. 'not a tar file' sounds a bit more concerning. Anyway, I have modified the 'deja-dup'-with-debug command line so it also puts debug data on the terminal as well as in the /tmp/deja-dup.log file so if you run it again then you can cut-paste the debug data into your question. (I think you added the 'duplicity' debug data last time).

Looking at the list of the backend (archive) you have posted it suggests that volume 1 & 2 are missing as they are normally generated in order.  To confirm this I would need to see the log which I requested in my last posting. If you would like to see a similar log to see what I mean posted on another answer see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1521682/deja-dup-backup-failed

I received a similar error message in my case because I had used cat to combine multiple .zip folders with Deja Dup contents into a single folder. (I had downloaded these contents from Google Drive, and due to their size, Google Drive split them into multiple folders.) DejaDup wasn't able to process this combined folder correctly.
I was able to resolve this issue by extracting each .zip folder individually; combining the contents into the same folder via copy and paste commands; and then having Deja Dup restore that folder. This time, I didn't receive the error.
This may not solve the issue you're experiencing, but hopefully this answer will help anyone who is also trying to restore a local copy of DejaDup files that originally existed on Google Drive.
