Deja Dup Backup Failed
I started using deja dup. After setting it up, the first backup is successful. But any further backup fails with the following error:
    Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 67, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 58, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1561, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1642, in do_backup
    restore(col_stats)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 810, in restore
    if not patchdir.Write_ROPaths(config.local_path, restore_get_patched_rop_iter(col_stats)):
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 861, in restore_get_patched_rop_iter
    file_names.append(backup_set.volume_name_dict[vol_num])
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
 KeyError: 1


When I start deja dup via terminal, I get:
deja-dup
mount: /home: „mount“ darf nur der Administrator verwenden.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
mount: /home: „mount“ darf nur der Administrator verwenden.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
mount: /home: „mount“ darf nur der Administrator verwenden.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
umount: /home: nur der Administrator kann umount ausführen.


So it seems like deja dup hasn't permission to access /home.
Is there any way to fix it?
deja dup logfile
List of files:
-rw-r--r-- 1 matthias matthias   1MB Jul 28 18:04 duplicity-full.20240728T155732Z.manifest.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 matthias matthias 210MB Jul 28 18:03 duplicity-full.20240728T155732Z.vol2.difftar.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 matthias matthias  28MB Jul 28 18:04 duplicity-full.20240728T155732Z.vol3.difftar.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 matthias matthias   7MB Jul 28 18:04 duplicity-full-signatures.20240728T155732Z.sigtar.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 matthias matthias   1MB Jul 29 08:08 duplicity-inc.20240728T155732Z.to.20240729T060835Z.manifest.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 matthias matthias   1MB Jul 29 08:08 duplicity-inc.20240728T155732Z.to.20240729T060835Z.vol1.difftar.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 matthias matthias   1MB Jul 29 09:00 duplicity-inc.20240729T060835Z.to.20240729T070005Z.manifest.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 matthias matthias   1MB Jul 29 09:00 duplicity-inc.20240729T060835Z.to.20240729T070005Z.vol1.difftar.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 matthias matthias   1MB Jul 29 09:05 duplicity-inc.20240729T070005Z.to.20240729T070517Z.manifest.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 matthias matthias   1MB Jul 29 09:05 duplicity-inc.20240729T070005Z.to.20240729T070517Z.vol1.difftar.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 matthias matthias   1MB Jul 29 08:08 duplicity-new-signatures.20240728T155732Z.to.20240729T060835Z.sigtar.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 matthias matthias   1MB Jul 29 09:00 duplicity-new-signatures.20240729T060835Z.to.20240729T070005Z.sigtar.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 matthias matthias   1MB Jul 29 09:05 duplicity-new-signatures.20240729T070005Z.to.20240729T070517Z.sigtar.gpg


may be related https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401018/how-effective-is-deja-dup-backups Personally I use Timeshift for backups. It seems more solid.

Can you append to the question a list of the generated files of the first successful run. Put them in date order with the oldest first. It might highlight the problem

Try running deja-dup from a command line in debug mode as follow: 'DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1 deja-dup | tail -n 200 > /tmp/deja-dup.log' and then appending the result (the file at the end or the command)  to the end of your original question

I attached a log file

Thanks for posting the logfile. Looking at the log (I am not an expert), it seems to find 1 full and three incremental backups  (13 files - which the log calls the 'backend'?)  (search 'backup'  in log).  Looking at the archive dir it reports the 'full backup' has 2 volumes present. Then it looks at the 'full backup' 'manifest' and determines there should be three volumes. Then it crashes. I think the full archive might be missing volume 3? How to fix? Mmm. Start of with posting a list of the files in the backend directory.

I added a list of files

Thanks for the list of files. I was hoping to find a miss-named files but as far as I can see all the other files are correct. 4 files for the full archive; Then 3 files for each of the three incremental updates =13 files. There should be 5 files in the full archive making a total of 14. You are missing data. It is, in fact, volume 1.  If it isn't available I can only think to attempt to extract each file but it will fail for the missing files if in vol1. The manifest files are ascii text files so you can explore with an editor to find out which files are retrievable.

I sort of ran out of room in the comment section so I have reproduced & extended it here.
Try running deja-dup from a command line in debug mode as follow:
'DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1 deja-dup | tail -n 200 > /tmp/deja-dup.log'

and then appending the result (the file at the end or the command) to the end of your original question. (All ready done.)
Thanks for posting the logfile.
Looking at the log (I am not an expert), it seems to find 1 full and three incremental backups (13 files - which the log calls the 'backend'?) (search 'backup' in log). Looking at the archive dir it reports the 'full backup' has 2 volumes present. Then it looks at the 'full backup' 'manifest' and determines there should be 3 volumes. Then it crashes.
After you posted a list of the archive it becomes apparent that volume 1 is missing.
I was hoping from the archive list to find a miss-named file but nothing is showing. It might be worth looking again to list, but showing all (hidden) files with ls -al  If you have copied or moved the archive it might be worth going back to the source to check there too. It might also be worth looking in the 'cache' which is where the target files are manipulated before depositing them in the archive. Location: -
$HOME/.cache/deja-dup/{CodedArchiveNumber}

I have multiple CodedArchiveNumber but I think this is because my {$HOME} has been in existence over many versions of Ubuntu. If you do have more than one you should look in the one with the most recent date.
You would expect to find and unencypted version of the manifests that you have view with an editor/viewer and this shows the volume and Hash (code to find target in a volume) of each directory. Make sure you do not update any of these files.
If you have copies of all the files the best thing to do is just start again with a new archive.
For files that only exist in the archive you should try to extract them. I believe it will let you do this provided the target file is not in the missing volume. If it is it will crash. Once you have extracted everything you should then build a new archive. It would be prudent to use a new archive and and mark the old one as damaged with a note of what it is so it can be deleted when you are absolutely sure you will never ever need anything in it again.
Why did you loose a volume? I can't really comment. Only to say that I found this archive method to be reliable and have 258 files in mine currently.

I think just running :
sudo deja-dup

Should give you permission to home directory.
But be careful about using sudo, you should not give root permission to anything you use, but in this case I think it's not dangerous.
But you should be able to access /home without superuser so here is some issues that might be happened and solution that may fixed them :
Maybe you don't have permission to home due to an external network or drive or anything else you can check and get the permission back by running :
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER

sudo chmod -R u+rw /home/$USER


Can you please explain this answer a bit more?

I think running deja-dup as a superuser should give it storage permission to some directories that are not available in normal mode. Like other situations

I understand this would solve the problem, but why I need to give superuser permission to the /home directory. Shouldn't it run with the permission of the user I started it with? And the backup job is set just to copy data from the /home directory of this user.

Yes you are correct, I edited my message and writed some issues that might be happened and how you may solve them

You should not run deja-dup as sudo except in very limited circumstances where you completely understand the implications. You should not globally change permissions or file ownerships in a directory unless you completely understand the implications. This answer is dangerous.

I have provided the right way that may work and also running a software like deja-dup might not be dangerous because it does most of things automatically.
